# Why is this an audit test?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just failed this audit: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/2095656

The question was: give me a book about a specific mathematical subject in physics.
The answer was: hereby a description of a book that uses general mathematics in a kind of physics.

It is very well possible that the mentioned book does not speak about the specific mathematical subject, which is asked for. But is this a reason to turn this answer into an audit test???

If there's some other reason why this should indeed be an audit test, please let me know.

Comment: Questions for the audit reviews are selected randomly by the software, so the only criteria it has access to are the upvotes/downvotes and whether or not the question was closed.  The software has no idea what the content of the question is, if it's good by today's standards, or anything else.  It's also, really, just a system test to make sure you're not mindlessly clicking through without paying attention, not a criticism of you or your efforts.  Try not to worry about failing one; worry if you're constantly failing them :)

Comment: This answer shows up in the audit test since it was marked as spam (The answerer seems to be the author of the mentioned book, and the answer indeed looks like a spam).

Comment: @postmortes: audit tests should not be created automatically, but should be carefully chosen or created by moderators or their colleagues. The simple fact to let review blocking depend on arbitrary actions, like up- or downvoting, is a serious hazard: a group of less than 10 people can agree to downvote some innocent questions or answers, the site turns those innocent posts into audit tests, and lots of people might get blocked from reviewing, due to a very simple act of sabotage.

Comment: @ArcticChar: in case a person makes publicity of his or her book, please add a comment to that answer, exposing this situation for other site members.

Comment: Well, what's the point of adding a comment to an answer that is already deleted?

Comment: @Dominique if you want to change how audits are done, you're on the wrong site.  You'll need to go to Meta for Stackoverflow for that.  But also, you don't get punished in *any* way for failing a single audit.  You get banned from reviewing (I think temporarily the first few times) if you *continually* fail audits, indicating you're not doing them properly.  If the community is well-functioning most audit questions should be good.  It's still not anything to get upset about.

Comment: (1) You cannot be blocked from reviewing via the automatic systems.  If you fail a lot of audits, a flag will be raised for moderators to look at.  Moderator action is then required to institute a review ban.  (2) Your solution to bad automatically generated audits is to have moderators select questions for audits.  How do you propose that we do this?  How much time are you expecting us to take on this task?  How frequently?